# how can i insert selected time in my spinner into my database?

Tags: java, swing

my need is to select an exact time for a travel and store it in my database , i don't have lot of experience in java so i will appriciate any help.
this is my jspinner:

```
    java.util.Date SDateU = new java.util.Date();
    Object SDATES = new java.sql.Date(SDateU.getTime()); 
    JSpinner.DateEditor timeEditor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(timeSpinner, "HH:mm:ss");
    timeSpinner.setEditor(timeEditor);
    timeSpinner.setValue(SDATES);
    timeSpinner.setBounds(317, 222, 107, 20);
    contentPane.add(timeSpinner);
```

and this is my insert buton :
i've tried to convert from java.util.date to java.sql.date but it didn't do the work

```
        btnAjouter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        String SNom_Societe="",SMatricul="",SLigne_Voyage="",STerminus="",STransit="";   int SNum_Quai;
           // java.sql.Timestamp timeSpinner = new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());
           // java.util.Date SDate_Depart; 
            java.util.Date SDate_Depart = new java.util.Date();
            Object sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(SDate_Depart.getTime()); 

            SNom_Societe= comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
            SMatricul = comboBox_1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            SLigne_Voyage = comboBox_2.getSelectedItem().toString();
            SNum_Quai = Integer.parseInt(comboBox_3.getSelectedItem().toString());
            STerminus = comboBox_4.getSelectedItem().toString();
            STransit = comboBox_5.getSelectedItem().toString();
            sqlDate = timeSpinner.getValue();


            try {
                String insertSQL="INSERT INTO t_voyage      (date_depart,matricul,nom_societe,ligne_voyage,num_quai,terminus,transit) VALUES (?,?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                PreparedStatement PS = con.prepareStatement(insertSQL);
                PS.setDate(1,  (java.sql.Date) sqlDate);
                PS.setString(2, SMatricul);
                PS.setString(3, SNom_Societe);
                PS.setString(4, SLigne_Voyage);
                PS.setInt(5, SNum_Quai);
                PS.setString(6, STerminus);
                PS.setString(7, STransit);
                PS.executeUpdate();
                System.out.println("ok it works!");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What does `didn't do the work` mean? Have you done any debugging? if so what were your findings?

Answer (score 0):

you are doing this:

`java.util.Date SDate_Depart = new java.util.Date();
            Object sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(SDate_Depart.getTime());`

and then doing this

`sqlDate = timeSpinner.getValue();`

Just do the conversion from java.util.Date from the timeSpinner to the java.sql.Date like you did in the first case.

Comment: Thanks but my line "sqlDate = timeSpinner.getValue();" is meant to get the value selected from the jspinner otherwise i can't get it!

Comment: Understood. This is returning a java.util.Date object, and you want to convert it into a java.sql.Date. So call new sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(timerSpinner.getValue().getTime())